# extract function instances and parameters from a string

Tags: r, regex

I would like a function that will find function instances in a string, extract the raw parameters,and replace them with placeholders.
Unfortunately my regex skills don't lead me far...

I would like the folowing behavior:

```
extract_fun("max(7*xy,b=z)+maximum+max(j)",fun="max")
# $modified_string
# [1] "{F[[1]]}+maximum+{F[[2]]}"
# 
# $params
# $params[[1]]
# [1] "7*xy" "b=z" 
# 
# $params[[2]]
# [1] "j"
```

Edit:

A more complicated use case:

```
extract_fun("max(7*xy,b=min(1,3))+maximum+max(j)",fun="max")
    # $modified_string
    # [1] "{F[[1]]}+maximum+{F[[2]]}"
    # 
    # $params
    # $params[[1]]
    # [1] "7*xy" "b=min(1,3)" 
    # 
    # $params[[2]]
    # [1] "j"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

Your function should have two arguments:

```
 fun = "max"
 string = "max(7*xy,b=z)+maximum+max(j)"
```

the regex captures anything in `(`, `)`, preceded by `fun` and it is lazy `?`

```
regex = paste0(fun, "\\((.*?)\\)")
regex
#output
"max\\((.*?)\\)"

matcher = stringr::str_match_all(string, regex)
matcher = do.call(rbind, matcher)
matcher
#output
     [,1]         [,2]      
[1,] "(7*xy,b=z)" "7*xy,b=z"
[2,] "(j)"        "j"       

#extract arguments from captured groups in matcher[,2]
params = strsplit(matcher[,2], " {0,}, {0,}" ) #, with possible white spaces before and after
#output
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy" "b=z" 

[[2]]
[1] "j"

#generate a modified_string
Fs = 1:nrow(matcher)
replacer = paste0("{F[[", Fs, "]]}")
regex2 = paste(matcher[,1])
out =  string
for (i in 1:length(replacer)){
  out= gsub(regex2[i], replacer[i], out , fixed = TRUE)
}
out
#output
"{F[[1]]}+maximum+{F[[2]]}"
```

EDIT: here is what I have so far on the updated question:

My idea is to isolate the part of the string with the function of interest and than manipulate this part only.

```
string = "max(7*xy,b=min(1,3))+maximum+max(j)"
```

Split string just behind `max(`

```
fun = "max"
regex_for_split = paste0("(?<=.)(?=", fun, "\\()")
fun_char = nchar(fun)    

spliter_begin = unlist(strsplit(string, regex_for_split, perl = TRUE))
```

Locate opening and ending parentheses

```
opening = stringr::str_locate_all(spliter_begin, "\\(")
ending = stringr::str_locate_all(spliter_begin, "\\)")
```

clean it up a bit

```
opening = lapply(opening, function(x){
  return((x[,1]))
})
ending = lapply(ending, function(x){
  return((x[,1]))
})
```

find at what position is the amount of ending parentheses equal to the amount of opened parentheses. We are interested in the first match.

```
out = list()
for (i in 1: length(ending)){
  end = ending[[i]]
  open = opening[[i]]
  sumer = vector()
  for(z in end){
    sumi=  sum(open < z) == sum(end<=z)
    sumer = c(sumer, sumi)
  }
  out[[i]] = sumer
  }

spliter_end = purrr::map2(ending, out, function(x, y){
  return(x[y])
})
```

isolate the sub string

```
fun_isolate = purrr::map2(as.list(spliter_begin), spliter_end, function(x,y){
  substr(x, start = fun_char+2, stop = y[1]-1)
})

fun_isolate
#output
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy,b=min(1,3)"

[[2]]
[1] "j"
```

lets try with a meaner example

```
string2 = "max(7*xy,b=min(1,3),z=sum(x*y)),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j)"
  #copy above code with `string2` instead of `string`
fun_isolate
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy,b=min(1,3),z=sum(x*y)"

[[2]]
[1] "j"
```

Or even tougher:

```
string3 = "max(7*xy,b=min(1,3, head(z)),z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j)"

#output
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy,b=min(1,3, head(z)),z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))"

[[2]]
[1] "j"
```

Now its just a matter of splitting at `,` not surrounded by `(` `)`.

```
#locate strings in parenthesis
locate_exclude = stringr::str_locate_all(unlist(fun_isolate), "\\(.*?\\)")
#locate all comas
locate_comma = stringr::str_locate_all(unlist(fun_isolate), ",")

#leave the difference
splt_locate  = purrr::map2(locate_exclude, locate_comma, function(x, y){
  if(length(x)==0) x = matrix(data=c(0,0), nrow=1)
  offbounds = vector()
  for (i in 1 : nrow(x)){
    z = x[i,1]:x[i,2]
    offbounds = c(offbounds, z)
  }
   comas = y[,1]
  return(comas[!comas%in%offbounds])
})
#function to split string at indexes
split_str_by_index <- function(target, index) {
  index <- sort(index)
  substr(rep(target, length(index) + 1),
         start = c(1, index),
         stop = c(index -1, nchar(target)))
}

close_but_not_yet = purrr::map2(fun_isolate, splt_locate, function(x, y){
   split_str_by_index(x, y)
  })
close_but_not_yet
#output
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy"                  ",b=min(1,3, head(z))"  ",z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))"

[[2]]
[1] "j"
```

And just remove `,` on the start of the string if there is one. Example:

```
lapply(close_but_not_yet , function(x) gsub("^, {0,}", "",x))
#output
[[1]]
[1] "7*xy"                 "b=min(1,3, head(z))"  "z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))"

[[2]]
[1] "j"
```

it won't work if the same function is called within itself like:

```
"max(7*xy,b=min(1,3),z=max(x*y)),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j)"
```

but even that could be manageable if you exclude all from `(` `)` prior the first strsplit like in the `,` example.

tested with:

```
"max(7*xy,b=min(1,3, head(z)),z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j)"
"max(7*xy,b=min(1,3, head(z)),z=sum(x*y+mean(x+y))),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j*z+sum(a*b^sum(z)), drop = 72)"
"max(7*xy,b=min(1,3, head(z)),z=sum(x*y, mean(x+y))),mean(x+y)+maximum+max(j*z+sum(a*b^sum(z)), drop = 72)"
```

Comment: Thanks! it works amazing on my example and probably on most cases i'll deal with, but any chance to make it work with `max(7*xy,b=min(1,3))+maximum+max(j)` ? I don't need it to handle recursion, but handling function calls inside function calls would be nice

Comment: Will there be other functions in the strings apart the ones in arguments of the desired function? like `"max(7*xy,b=min(1,3))+mean(b,z)+maximum+max(j)"`

Comment: Are the characters between the function calls also present inside the function calls? For instance in the above examples `+` is never in any function calls.

Comment: Yes to both questions ideally

Comment: is there some list of characters that can be outside function calls, or is it any characters? I mean specifically after the `)` closing the functions - only mathematical operators like: `+,-,*,/,%%,%/%,^`?

Comment: can there be `),` outside a function call?

Comment: yes, to be transparent I'll use it to translate some R statement in SQL, so the string could be any possible query in principle, though in practice the solution you proposed will really work in most cases. I realize the general solution may involve counting brackets, checking if commas are under the right brackets etc, or do the whole thing recursively starting with the deepest nested brackets pairs, quite complex!